# Overcoming "It is being used by another person or program."

Tags: windows, permissions, locking

Is there a way to unlock Windows files without downloading a utility?

I have a few files on my Windows XP C: drive that are very old and very useless.  When I try to delete these files I get the following message:

```
Cannot delete FILENAME.zip: It is being used by another person or program

Close any programs that might be using the file and try again.
```

No one is accessing this file.  No program is using it currently.  Windows has screwed up the file locking mechanism.

Is there a way to delete this file without downloading someone's unlocking utility?  I find the sites offering these programs to be a tad sketchy.

How could you force the file to unlock from within a program?  I'm competent in Java, Perl, and Ruby, but I haven't seen anything among their libraries that would aid me here.

Comment: The question had been closed as not programming related.  I re-opened and added a line at the bottom to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Since he isn't asking for a programmable solution, don't you think that is a little disingenuous? If you think it would be beneficial to discuss programmatic file lock discovery, shouldn't that be a separate question?

Comment: I closed the question because SO is not for IT questions. The edit has changed the author's meaning, which edits aren't supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for re-opening/editing.  I understand that this is not a programming question per se.  But fiddling with Windows processes and file locks has a lot more to do with development work than questions about "What is your favorite (programmer cartoon|keyboard|t-shirt)?"

Comment: This is definitely a programming related question. There are many scenarios where this problem would crop up during development, such as when testing installers or plugins. Just because the question isn't framed as a programming scenario doesn't mean it's not a legit SO question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've successfully used Process Explorer to find out which process has the file open. It saves a reboot that may not fix the problem anyway.

In process explorer: Find > Handle or DLL... then search for the name of the folder/file, then double click one of the search results. It'll select a handle in the main window, which you can right click and close.

Comment: One step further with Process Explorer: after using the Find Handle or DLL window, double click one of the search results. It'll select a handle in the main window, which you can right click and close.

Comment: His original question stated that he didn't want to download a third-party tool.

Comment: Well if he thinks the Microsoft site where you would download this from is "Sketchy" in his words (his reason for not wanting to download), then I doubt he would trust any other advice anyway.

Comment: This isn't a third party tool. It's published by Microsoft.

Comment: File handle feature of Process Explorer is really cool.

Comment: In process explorer: Find > Handle or DLL... then search for the name of the folder/file and close the process that owns it.

Answer (score 8):

Try downloading "Unlocker". Google it and take my words that it doesn't have any worm/spyware/virus. It is pretty cool utility and works great. Give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try the commandline command [OpenFiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732490.aspx)

It is built in (XP and above I believe) and has several arguments that can be passed in.

Answer (score 2):

Use msconfig and start up with everything turned off.

Then try to move / delete the file.

Or you can always boot up in safe mode and delete it.

You do that by hitting f8 when the machine boots up.

Answer (score 1):

If you reboot and the files are still locked, then there is some process on your machine that **is** still using them. First you should figure out what that process is and determine if the files really aren't used any more or not.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting to Safe Mode is often a very easy way to do it.  When you boot in safe mode, it won't load all the stuff set to run on startup.  Press F8 while it's booting to access the boot menu, and choose "safe mode".

Answer (score 1):

I had a .jpg pfile that hasd that issue and I couldn't delete. That brought me to this thread. When nothing else worked I renamed the file and left off the .jpg. THEN I could delete it easily. Not sure why, but worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any utility.
Just use Win32 api to unlock them (simply close the handle)