# the action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program

Tags: windows-7

When deleting a folder that contains a file that is in use, it is common to see the following Windows 7 message,

> "The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program."

I commonly have 10-20 programs open, 30-40 folders open, etc. In short, I have many executables running and many windows explorers open.

Does anyone know a simple trick to determine *which* program is using the file?
Does anyone know a simple trick to determine *which* file is blocking the delete operation?

This information would be highly useful to display in the Windows 7 'folder in use' dialog, but it is missing.

Consequently I have to close many of my open applications and folders to complete the delete operation. This is annoying because I have to re-open them after deleting them.

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229851/overcoming-it-is-being-used-by-another-person-or-program) or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/easy-way-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)?

I use to run ProccessExplorer and Find for the blocked folder.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the application Malwarebytes allowed me to delete what I needed to via Windows Explorer.